# Excel VBA .Move doesn't keep format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy (or move) multiple .csv files into one excel-file.

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook
Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
fPath = "xyz\"  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")   
On Error Resume Next
Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)                
    wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete                   
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)   
    Columns.AutoFit           
    fCSV = Dir                  
Loop
```

For some reason, if I have numbers separarted by ",", Excel doesn't switch this to a number but keeps it as a text (whole numbers become numbers).
I asked a friend to run the code and for him it works fine...

Comment: what is your current output and what is an example of desired output?

Comment: I have Values in the .csv in the format of e.g. 5,85. The output should be a number. The current output is this cell/row gets converted into a string so I'm not able to calculate with it. If I transform the .csv into an excel file manually the numbers become numbers but with this code, it becomes a string..

Comment: using `cINT()` will convert a string to a number.

Comment: Ah yes, I also have Strings (like Names, etc). Will a cINT() still work?

Comment: `cINT()` will convert a number from text to an integer. If the string is alpha numeric, it will not work because it is a string.

Comment: Then it is not working...

Comment: Do you know the columns where the data to be transferred is numeric and must be preserved as numeric? Do all involved csv files have the same number of columns?

Comment: I am asking about that, not to satisfy my curiosity. I can suggest a solution, for a specific situation...